# Generate jasmine report using Karma Runner

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner

I want to obtain a report of all successful jasmine specs runned with karma, something like you obtain when using jasmine alone.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Bump, want to see if anyone else has some input on this!

Comment: I posted a github issue for this: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/564

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this quick plugin I wrote:

https://github.com/dtabuenc/karma-html-reporter

Comment: Woks good, although has some issue with styling(CSS). As characters are overlapping. http://cl.ly/image/1w2y0U3T1E0c

Answer (score 8):

## tl;dr

Yes, but it's non-trivial, and even more so if you want `--auto-watch`. So, basically, no :-( Blame it on [lib/reporters/Progress.js](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/v0.9.2/lib/reporters/Progress.js), which swallows successful test results and spits out a summary line for each browser.

If you're determined, though, you have (at least) two non-trivial ways (in **[v0.9.2](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/tree/v0.9.2)**) of getting a "good enough" result (one of which, if you do it, you should polish up and submit as a pull request :-))

## Option 1: jUnit scraping

As with most test frameworks, you can get Karma to output results in the [jUnit XML format](http://windyroad.com.au/dl/Open%20Source/JUnit.xsd), which you can then post-process...

By default, `karma start --reporters=junit` will write a jUnit report to `${basePath}/test-results.xml`, but you can override this with the `junitReporter.outputFile` config item.

Keep in mind that you can combine the jUnit output with other reporters (growl, etc.) on the command-line: e.g., `karma start --reporters=junit,growl`

### Post-processing with ant

- [how can i create a html report for the junit xml report manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589956/how-can-i-create-a-html-report-for-the-junit-xml-report-manually) [(ant mojo)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8590169)
- [How can I generate an HTML report for Junit results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385553/how-can-i-generate-an-html-report-for-junit-results)

### Post-processing with XSLT

- [What XSLT converts JUnit Xml format to JUnit Plain format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470060/what-xslt-converts-junit-xml-format-to-junit-plain-format) [(with stylesheet!)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9471505)

### Post-processing with xmlstarlet

I've always ended up rolling my own stupid grep/sed/perl/etc. pipeline in cases like this, but [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sf.net/) is perfect for this job. E.g.,

```sh
$ cat test-runner.xml \
    | xml sel -t -m "//testcase" -v @classname -o " " -v @name -nl
```

yields (for one of my projects):

```
Chrome 27.0 (Linux).Globalization API: _g11n exists
Chrome 27.0 (Linux).Globalization API: _g11n has been initialized
Chrome 27.0 (Linux).Globalization API: _g11n _locales exists
Chrome 27.0 (Linux).Globalization API: _g11n _locales has been initialized
Chrome 27.0 (Linux).Globalization API: _g11n _locales has a current locale (matching the default)
Chrome 27.0 (Linux).Globalization API: _g11n _locales registry allows lookup by full code
Chrome 27.0 (Linux).Globalization API: _g11n _locales registry allows lookup by locale object
Chrome 27.0 (Linux).Globalization API: _g11n _locales registry fails
Chrome 27.0 (Linux).Globalization controllers hkmLocaleCtrl should have the locales database
```

## Option 2: Write a Custom Reporter

If you're up for it, subclass an existing reporter (e.g., `lib/reporters/Progress.js`, `lib/reporters/Base.js`), overriding the `.specSuccess` and `.onBrowserComplete` methods to report more details from each test. Getting karma to use the reporter is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

BTW: If you choose option 2, be sure to open a pull-request to get it into karma :-)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!
I think I will try to go for option 2.
I have karma installed with node at './.npm/karma/0.8.5/package/lib', I tried to modify that file (by deleting all basically to see if it fails), but no change is reflected in karma. Is there another place I should look for?

Comment: That's the "pristine" cached copy of the package. Use `npm prefix` and `npm prefix -g` to find the local and global package installs, respectively. Alternatively, `mkdir foo ; cd foo ; npm install karma` then edit the copy in `foo/node_modules/karma`. This is a hackish way of doing it, but I haven't done enough NPM development to know the "right" way, yet. I know it starts with `git clone https://github.com/karma-runner/karma` :-), and, for karma, continues with notes here: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: I vote for option 2, with Karma 0.9+ (currently in canary), you can easily add custom plugins (eg. reporters/launchers/adapters/etc).

So write a new reporter, you can get inspiration in https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-junit-reporter

Comment: Would love this also, but writing a plug in is above my ability, so sorry I can't take it on.

Answer (score 2):

To show the individual test case I use the following (starting from scratch for a basic unit test project):

```
npm install karma karma-jasmine karma-phantomjs-launcher karma-spec-reporter

touch main.js main.spec.js

karma init
```

then to the following questions select:

```
Which testing framework do you want to use ?
> jasmine

Do you want to capture any browsers automatically ?
> PhantomJS
> 

What is the location of your source and test files ?
> *.js

Do you want Karma to watch all the files and run the tests on change ?
> yes
```

edit the **karma.conf.js** in your project folder and

replace:

*reporters: ['progress']*

with:

**reporters: ['spec']**

run

```
karma start
```

and you are ready to write your unit test in the main.spec.js

```
describe('suite', function () {
    it('expectation', function () {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

save... and in the terminal you should see something like:

```
INFO [watcher]: Changed file"/main.spec.js".
true
  ✓ should be true

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.001 secs / 0 secs)
```

Comment: this is the perfect answer to my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462961/display-jasmine-spec-results-in-console question

Answer (score 0):

There's karma-coverage which creates .html code coverage reports. It's straight-forward to integrate it into your karma config.

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage

```
npm install karma-coverage --save-dev
```

add to karma.conf.js:

```
// karma.conf.js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    files: [
      'src/**/*.js',
      'test/**/*.js'
    ],

    // coverage reporter generates the coverage
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

    preprocessors: {
      // source files, that you wanna generate coverage for
      // do not include tests or libraries
      // (these files will be instrumented by Istanbul)
      'src/*.js': ['coverage']
    },

    // optionally, configure the reporter
    coverageReporter: {
      type : 'html',
      dir : 'coverage/'
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted you, but I think you misunderstood the question. Coverage reports only show code coverage for each file, not each individual test cases.