# How can I get a list of passing tests from karma runner suite?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner

When I run karma on my webapp, I only get generic messages like tests passed - is there a way to get a list of passing tests? How do I get more verbose output?

I cannot find this anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684582/generate-jasmine-report-using-karma-runner/16865197?noredirect=1#comment24382342_16865197

Answer (score 61):

I know how this can be done!

Karma's terminal output comes from objects called Reporters.  Karma ships with some built-in Reporters (they can be found in `karma/lib/reporters`).  Karma is also able to use custom Reporters.

You can specify which reporters are used in your project's `karma.config.js` file.

For example, the 'dots' reporter just prints a dot when each test passes:

```
reporters: ['dots'],
```

The 'progress' reporter prints more than dots:

```
reporters: ['progress'],
```

The custom reporter [karma-spec-reporter](https://github.com/mlex/karma-spec-reporter) prints the name of each test when the test succeeds or fails (but not much else):

```
reporters: ['spec'],
```

You may want to roll your own reporter, since karma-junit-reporter, karma-spec-reporter, and the included reporters may not meet your needs.

I am guessing that customizing karma-spec-reporter is the best option in this case, since it already prints a line when a test succeeds.

If you are looking for something even more simple to work from, [here](https://github.com/argocode/karma-argo-reporter) is a custom reporter that I built.  It reports passing and failing tests with no terminal colors.

Comment: Install karma-spec-reporter via `npm install karma-spec-reporter --save-dev`. Hope that helps someone as it was unclear to me how to use.

Comment: thanks @AnsonKao also need to specify `karma-spec-reporter` in plugins section of `karma.conf`

Answer (score 56):

I recommend the Karma Spec Reporter. This will give you a pretty unit test report like this.

[image: Karma unit test spec]

How to use it:

1. Install the Karma Spec Reporter

> On the command line in your project,
>
> `npm install karma-spec-reporter --save-dev`

2. Add Karma Spec Reporter to the configuration

> In `karma.conf.js`,
>
> ```
> ...
>   config.set({
>   ...
>     reporters: ["spec"],
>     specReporter: {
>       maxLogLines: 5,         // limit number of lines logged per test
>       suppressErrorSummary: true,  // do not print error summary
>       suppressFailed: false,  // do not print information about failed tests
>       suppressPassed: false,  // do not print information about passed tests
>       suppressSkipped: true,  // do not print information about skipped tests
>       showSpecTiming: false // print the time elapsed for each spec
>     },
>     plugins: ["karma-spec-reporter"],
>   ...
> ```

That is all. Enjoy.

Comment: Hi @Matt, I follow the instructions, but when I run ng test I saw the same interface, what did you do to get the format that you shows in the image

Comment: Hm, I had to remove the 'progress' from my reporters array. This is what I use now: 
   reporters: ['kjhtml', 'spec'], 
Then I can see both in the console and in the Chrome that is launched the tests passing

Answer (score 9):

Use this plugin with karma 0.9.0 or later

https://github.com/mlex/karma-spec-reporter

Answer (score 1):

You could add logs to your test spec. Check out log4js-node:

https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node