# Converting XML JUnit report to HTML

Tags: xslt, selenium, protractor

I have been generating junit xml report till now for my Protractor tests, but as tests are increasing I need to get a HTML report for the tests.
Can we change the junit xml report to HTML using XSLT?
If yes, can I have XSLT file for the same.

Comment: yes.. you can translate XML into HTML using XSLT.. Here is a w3school XLST 'client' example. http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp.. which uses Ajax and XHR object to do so.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has created a generic XSL style sheet to use for transforming JUnit XML output.  If there was one, you could obviously use it to transform the xml.  If you search google hard enough I bet you could find one.

Comment: I've been after this for years, so I finally sat down the other day to fulfil this aim. I've created `junit2html` and it can be found here: https://github.com/inorton/junit2html

Comment: This tool will also transform your junit XML file into a nice-looking HTML file : https://www.npmjs.com/package/junit-viewer Doesn't allow for much (any) style modifications as far as I can tell, but if that's not an issue, it's worth a look

Comment: If you like javascript and its environment the library [grunt-junit-report](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-junit-report) uses a xslt process to generate some HTML files.

Answer (score 5):

The solution can be to convert JUnit XML files to HTML files using the XSLT . You can find the XSLT file in the answer of this question: [What XSLT converts JUnit Xml format to JUnit Plain format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470060/what-xslt-converts-junit-xml-format-to-junit-plain-format)

You can use XSLT to create custom manual reports as in [Custom JUnit Report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727616/custom-junit-report)

You can use Ant to create HTML reports as in [how can i create a html report for the junit xml report manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589956/how-can-i-create-a-html-report-for-the-junit-xml-report-manually)